# Pandoc can't convert to pdf, `xcolor.sty' not found

Tags: linux, latex, pandoc

When I try to convert a file to pdf format with pandoc I receive this message:

```
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: File `xcolor.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.36 \IfFileExists
```

Does anyone know how to acquire the xcolor.sty file or some other way of fixing this? I'm using Linux.

Comment: Which tex distribution do you use? texlive, tinytex or something else?

Comment: texlive-latex-base and texlive-latex-extra are the core packages I used.

Comment: Maybe try the recommended collection, see with tex.stackexchange.com/a/43110/36296 ? (if you aren't short on disk space, I would ditch the linux packaged texlive and install a full texlive from tug.org - you'll never again have to worry about missing packages)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Something to check out, will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I wound up having to use (so far) was to install the package `weasyprint` and use the argument `--pdf-engine=weasyprint`. Nothing else seemed to work.